# Adding an anchor tag to list items making the list items disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question on here, so apologies if it isn't worded correctly.
I'm trying to make a popup mobile navigation menu with jQuery, but when I add anchor tags to my list items, they disappear. Here's the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <button id="nav-open">&#9776;</button>
    <div id="menu">
        <button id="nav-close"> X </button>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://foo.com">Home</a></li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Events</li>
            <li>Gallery</li>
            <li>Booking</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$("#nav-open").click(function(event){
   $("#menu").show();
   $(this).addClass("active");
   event.preventDefault();
});

$("#nav-close").click(function(event){
   $("#menu").hide();
   $(this).removeClass("active");
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

When a user clicks on #nav-open on a mobile device, it brings up the popup menu. (And when #nav-close is clicked, vice-versa.) I'm trying to add anchor tags to the list items but for whatever reason when I 
add links to #menu's li's, the text disappears completely.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the CSS:

```
  #menu {
   background: #000;
   opacity: 0.95;
   font-family: Arial Narrow;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: left;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 30px;
   margin-right: 5%;
   height: 60px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 260px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the non-working code, not the working code ?

Comment: Like @adeneo said- we can't help you if you show us what is working. We need to see what isn't working to help you

Comment: You're sure you don't have any CSS that styles anchor so the text disappears.

Comment: The issue isn't with the code you just posted- it works fine. The error being cause must be elsewhere. How large is your code?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited it to show the problem. Here's a link to a JSBin that might help too.

http://jsbin.com/cizopenonu/

Comment: @Zack105 Code isn't too large. Would it be helpful if I posted the entirety of all the code?

Comment: I don't think it'd hurt- I think it's a CSS style which is causing it to be invisible

Comment: Just a question: why are you using jQuery to do this? All of what you're trying to do can be done with simple CSS, and a little refactoring of the HTML. No need for javascript to make such a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with any of the code you posted- it's in the CSS. You have this style declared:

```
nav a {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Not sure why you have it, but that's definitely the cause. Simply deleting this will solve your issue.

**Update:** The CSS is in this file: http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/styles/styleKendall.css

Comment: I knew it would be a simple fix! Thank you so much. Issue solved.